# Is Khamûl an Easterling?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

Is Khamûl an Easterling?

"The Second Chief (the Black Easterling)"_ appears in a rejected version while in the present version of the passage which refers to "Khamûl" as "the Shadow of the East". Could we say that Tolkien's "Black Easterling" might have been rejected for "Shadow of the East"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your question here already covers everything there is to know about the issue.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the purpose of the site. This isn’t a forum where you open the discussion with a post and the rest of us comment on it. This is a Q&A site, where the original post needs to be a question, clear and explicit, and the responses are answers solving that question. In this case I suggest you move the majority of your text into an answer and answer your own question.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question answers itself and provides all the details that exist about this question.

Comment: Kemal, welcome to Stack Exchange! Please consider **[edit]ing the *answer* part out of your question and posting it below as an answer instead** - it's perfectly OK to answer your own question. Let the question stand as "Is Khamul an Easterling?" and post all your evidence/answer to that question down below as an actual answer.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I'm not sure why you voted _unanimously_ to leave this question open if you yourself say it answers yourself? Surely it should be closed until it's edited until it can be re-opened, otherwise what is the point of closing things?

Comment: @Edlothiad OP can't post his answer as an answer if it's closed, now can he? There's still a question here ("Is Khamul an Easterling?") - if you want, feel free to edit out the answery stuff yourself.

Comment: Hmm, I'd forgotten that was the case, more reasonable in that case but still quite strange given 19 hours have passed since OP was informed

Answer (score 7):

Probably. According to the index to the Unfinished Tales, 'Easterling' is (in Third Age usage)

> a general term for the waves of Men driving in upon Gondor from the
> eastern regions of Middle-earth

The grouping includes the Wainriders and the Balchoth but not the Variags of Khand, who are listed separately among the combatants at the Pelennor Fields. If we accept the main version of the Hunt for the Ring as canon (a bit dubious since it does not appear to have progressed beyond a fairly rough state) then either:

1. Khamul is an Easterling. This agrees with the rejected version and fits with his  description as the 'Shadow of the East' in the main version.
2. Khamul is not an Easterling, but travelled to the east (perhaps sent by Sauron)
   and there gained the epithet 'Shadow of the East'. This agrees with the main version     but not the rejected version.

I would be minded to go with (1), but I don't think there is any absolute proof.

Comment: The Variags would probably fall under Southrons more than Easterlings.  Khand is the southeast corner of Middle-Earth as mapped, just south of Mordor's eastern edge.

Comment: @suchiuomizu --- Easterlings, Southrons and Variags are all mentioned separately in the same sentence in The Battle of the Pelennor Fields, so I think Variags are a distinct group.

Comment: @Ian Thompson I communicated with the Marquette University for researching about the Khamûl and his origin (research on the Hunt for the Rings manuscripts). However, I did not find any further about “Eastness”. What should I do to find an answer?

Comment: There probably isn't any more you can do. There are many mysteries in Tolkien's work.